# Register file forwarding in MIPS

Tags: cpu, mips, cpu-architecture

I am reading section 4.7 in in Computer Organization and Design: The Hardware/Software Interface on data forwarding. In the example given in the book, there is register file forwarding.(This is exactly how it appears in the book [example](https://books.google.com/books?id=H7wxDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA298&lpg=PA298&dq=register+file+forwarding&source=bl&ots=bCWJPrpl8V&sig=9sFzV_jYbRHrEygK2nPM0RpdFIw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwickuPOzt_UAhWHxYMKHRKKB0gQ6AEIVTAJ#v=onepage&q=register%20file%20forwarding&f=false))

Why do you need register file forwarding? Data in the register is written in the first half of the clock and read in the second half of the clock, so it should be safe without forwarding.

Just to clarify the example given in the link above: Left side shading of `Reg` means it being written into, right - being read from.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Figure 4.53 of Computer Organization and Design, (c)2009 Elsevier]

You need register file forwarding to prevent stalls.

If you look closely the second instruction (`and $12, $2, $5`) needs to use register `$2`, but the value computed in the previous instruction (`sub $2, $1, $3`) will get written back in the register file in clock cycle 5. Therefore if it wasn't because of register file forwarding, the second instruction would have to stall until register `$2` were written back. The forwarding is shown with a skyblue line between the result of the ALU operation of instruction 1 and the first argument to the ALU operation of instruction 2.

Likewise, the third instruction (`or $13, $6, $2`) also needs to use $2 before it is actually written back to the register file by the first instruction. Therefore again, to prevent stalls, register forwarding is used to use the result of the first instruction in as an argument to the third instruction.

On the other hand, the fourth instruction (`add $14, $2, $2`) does not need to use pipeline register forwarding, as the result of the first instruction is written back in the first half of cycle 5 and therefore its contents are already updated when they are needed in the fourth instruction.

Comment: This is about data forwarding, but not specifically internal register forwarding.

Answer (score 2):

Since the accepted answer doesn't actually answer the question at hand, I'll give a try here. If your design writes data in the first half and reads in the second half, then you wouldn't have an issue. However an actual "register" will write data at the positive edge of the clock, so the above is not true. In the case where two instructions are reading and writing the same register, data must be forwarded from the write input of the register file to the read output during the same cycle.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** This example is with AT&T syntax
I would like to provide a software perspective on this. Here's an example with a single issue 6-stage(F,D,R,E,W,N) pipeline.
Notice the dependency on **%rax**. Our second instruction is dependent on the first instruction to change the value of **%rax** before it can use it.

```
imulq $2   %rax
addq  %rcx %rax
```

With register file forwarding, we can use the computed value of **%rax** in the execution stage and forward the results to the next instruction's read stage.

```
imulq $2   %rax: F D R E W N
addq  %rcx %rax:   F D D R E W N
```

Without register file forwarding we have to wait(stall) for the value to be written back to our register before we're able to read it.

```
imulq $2   %rax: F D R E W N
addq  %rcx %rax:   F D D D D R E W N
```

In summary, for this example, register forwarding saves us two cycles by allowing us to read our dependent value(**%rax**) after the execution stage of the previous instruction. I hope this helps.

Comment: You have a 64-bit multiply unit with single-cycle latency?  That must limit the max clock speed a lot, since the cycle time has to be long enough for many many gate delays.  `shl $1, %rax` would be a better example. (AT&T syntax requires commas between operands).  I assume this is y86-64 or something, as there haven't been any commercial x86-64 CPUs with single-issue in-order pipelines (64-bit Atom was in-order dual-issue, as were the P5-based cores in first-gen Xeon Phi KNC). And x86-64 instructions like `add %eax, (%rdi)` don't pipeline easily.  This is a MIPS question.

Comment: The lowest latency `imul` in any of the CPUs in Agner Fog's instruction tables (https://agner.org/optimize/) is Via Nano 3000 with `imul r32, r32` (or immediate source) at 2 cycle latency.  It's a low-power CPU not aimed at high clocks.  But that's only for 32-bit operand-size: 64-bit has 5 cycle latency there.  (vs. 3 cycle on mainstream Intel and AMD since Zen).